# Deleted the Windows EFI partition, What to do?

Tags: uefi, pop-os, systemd-boot

I installed Pop-OS in a dual-boot system.

Previously, my EFI partition was around 250mb. Pop Installer told me that it was too small. So instead of resizing and moving (due to possibility of data loss and Windows not booting), I deleted the old EFI partition and created a new EFI partition for install.

Output of `efibootmgr`:

```
BootCurrent: 0006
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0006,0007,0002
Boot0002* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0006* Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS
Boot0007* UEFI OS
```

Output of `bootctl`:

```
System:
     Firmware: UEFI 2.70 (American Megatrends 5.13)
  Secure Boot: disabled
   Setup Mode: user

Current Boot Loader:
      Product: systemd-boot 245.4-4ubuntu3.6pop0~1617377648~20.04~eafddeb
     Features: ✓ Boot counting
               ✓ Menu timeout control
               ✓ One-shot menu timeout control
               ✓ Default entry control
               ✓ One-shot entry control
               ✓ Support for XBOOTLDR partition
               ✓ Support for passing random seed to OS
               ✓ Boot loader sets ESP partition information
          ESP: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/06919b6c-bed1-461e-9b6d-04dc9597fd38
         File: └─/EFI/SYSTEMD/SYSTEMD-BOOTX64.EFI

Random Seed:
 Passed to OS: yes
 System Token: set
       Exists: yes

Available Boot Loaders on ESP:
          ESP: /boot/efi (/dev/disk/by-partuuid/06919b6c-bed1-461e-9b6d-04dc9597fd38)
         File: └─/EFI/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi (systemd-boot 245.4-4ubuntu3.6pop0~1617377648~20.04~eafddeb)
         File: └─/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI (systemd-boot 245.4-4ubuntu3.6pop0~1617377648~20.04~eafddeb)

Boot Loaders Listed in EFI Variables:
        Title: Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS
           ID: 0x0006
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/06919b6c-bed1-461e-9b6d-04dc9597fd38
         File: └─/EFI/SYSTEMD/SYSTEMD-BOOTX64.EFI

        Title: UEFI OS
           ID: 0x0007
       Status: active, boot-order
    Partition: /dev/disk/by-partuuid/06919b6c-bed1-461e-9b6d-04dc9597fd38
         File: └─/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI

Boot Loader Entries:
        $BOOT: /boot/efi (/dev/disk/by-partuuid/06919b6c-bed1-461e-9b6d-04dc9597fd38)

Default Boot Loader Entry:
        title: Pop!_OS
           id: Pop_OS-current.conf
       source: /boot/efi/loader/entries/Pop_OS-current.conf
        linux: /EFI/Pop_OS-39f0e06d-54c4-4fd3-af74-605fcd37bc55/vmlinuz.efi
       initrd: /EFI/Pop_OS-39f0e06d-54c4-4fd3-af74-605fcd37bc55/initrd.img
      options: root=UUID=39f0e06d-54c4-4fd3-af74-605fcd37bc55 ro quiet loglevel=0 systemd.show_status=false splash
```

There is no Windows in EFI variables.
I increased the timeout of systemd-boot to 5 seconds, and now I see *Pop OS* and *Boot to System Firmware*.

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/628581/474303) answer required the Windows EFI partition, which I deleted. Is there a way to get Windows Entry in systemd-boot?

Gparted (if it matters):
[image: Gparted]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this answer on askUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/949197/1341748), I used [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Main_Page) to recover the data in the deleted EFI partition.

I copied the Microsoft folder from `/boot/efi/EFI` in the deleted EFI partition and copied it to the same destination but in the new efi partition. And Voila! Windows Boot Manger showed up in the systemd-boot menu.

Answer (score 4):

I recently had some similar issues.
If your EFI partition data is unrecoverable, you can boot into Windows install media, a Windows 10 disc or a flash drive with the [Win 10 image](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) flashed.
Once booted into the installation media:

- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open command prompt,
  then execute the following commands:
- `diskpart`
- `list disk`
- `sel disk #` (replace # with the disk number containing the new ESP/EFI partition)
- `list part`
- `sel part #` (replace # with the fat32 EFI partition number)
- `assign letter=s`
- `list vol` Take note of the drive letter Windows OS has been assigned.
- `exit`
- `bcdboot X:\windows /s s:` (Replace X with the letter corresponding to the windows installation)

Now you can add the Windows entry to **/boot/efi/loader/loader.conf** manually & add a timeout to delay booting to the default OS & allow yourself time to choose during startup.

- Boot into Pop!_OS
- Open a terminal
- Run `sudo nano /boot/efi/loader/entries/windows.conf`
- Paste the following into the document:

```
title Windows 10
efi /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
#you may need to search for your bootmgfw.efi if it's not here
```

- Save and exit
- Run `sudo nano /boot/efi/loader/loader.conf`
- Add this line `timeout 20` (enter any value in seconds)
- Add this line to prevent duplicate entries of Windows `auto-windows 0`
- Optionally, set a default OS by adding another line & using it's title
  `default "Windows 10"` or `default "Pop!_OS"`
- Save and exit

Done!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, very unexpected, I changed a sata disk for an nvme disk - had to completely reinstall windows which is fine these days with all the data in the cloud - but I did not notice it wrote the boot files to an efi folder on a second Sata SSD coming from an earlier windows usage.. No problems recreating the Windows environement until I decided to install Ubuntu on that second disk.. In order to prepare I booted with a LiveUSB and with gparted wiped the /dev/sdb completely and prepared partitions for Ubuntu. Restarted the PC only to encounter the error that there could no OS to be found. I inspected again with liveUSB gparted & mounting the EFI just to find out that there was no more EFI partition with data.. the one on the nvm disk was empty. Kinda in despair I looked for a solution, found this page. having confidence, I once more did an Ubuntu LiveUSB gparted and created room for 1500Mb EFI partition on the nvme disk, gparted elegantly allow you to manage the flags for which I set the boot&system and removed those from the 100Mb partition at the start of the nvme disk. Rebooted using a windows recovery USB; select the repair option, enter command prompt and alle the commands above until and including the bcdboot (dont forget to replace X with the actual windows partiion drive letter) - reboot and Alive!