# Grub 2.06 does'nt display Pop-OS and Windows11

Tags: windows, dual-boot, pop-os

I decided to switch to Linux, for that I chose Pop-OS.
But in order not to make the change too brutal, I decided to have a dual boot with Windows11.
When I started up I went directly to Pop-OS.
I went on with the installation and the parameter setting of Grub 2.06 but I get this :
[Grub 2.06](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd5vM.jpg)

Just type "exit" and the computer boots on Pop-OS. If I play with parameters in the BIOS, it can boot on Windows 11 without any problem.
But I would like to have the choice during the boot, it will be more simple ;-)

In the terminal when I type

```
sudo update-grub
```

I get this :

```
    Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.0.12-76060006-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.0.12-76060006-generic
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sdb2@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

So it detects both OS well.

Here is what I have in the /etc/default/grub file

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Could you please help me to have Windows11 and Pop-os choice in boot menu ?

Comment: I thought Pop-OS used SystemD-Boot as its default, not grub2? This will not work for SystemD boot, as its most common fixes are grub updates or total reinstall of grub. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Be sure to boot in UEFI mode. Many Windows 11 systems now only have UEFI.

Comment: I would like to use SystemD Boot but I doesn't detect Windows (but it detect Pop-OS) So if you have a solution to have SystemD Boot detect Windows 11 I'll go with it

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/610779/pop-os-systemd-boot-cant-detect-windows

Comment: I find a olution here : 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/610779/pop-os-systemd-boot-cant-detect-windows

Now Windows11 and pop-os are displayed by SystemD boot so I can choose and all is working fine !

Thanks all